# Find duplicate key in embedded sub document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to craft a query that will allow me to find **duplicate** keys in *subdocument* in MongoDB.

It needs to be able to query any number of documents and see what keys are duplicated across them in a subdocument.  The key of my subdocument is called `attributes` and I need to be able to target a particular query of documents and pull out duplicate attribute keys that they all share.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I do not know the names of the attributes ahead of time.  I need to be able to essentially select distinct attributes that they share and aggregate the values.

Collection Sample:

```js
[
    {
        sku: '123',
        attributes: {
            size: 'L',
            custom: 7
        }
    },
    {
        sku: '456',
        attributes: {
            size: 'M'
        }
    },
    {
        sku: 'abc',
        attributes: {
            material: 'cotton'
            size: 'S'
        }
    }
]
```

Desired Result (if possible):

```js
{
   size: [' S', 'M', 'L']
}
```

If the desired result is not possible I would at least like to be able to get back `[ 'size' ]`

This process needs to be optimized as much as possible and I just cant seem to get a query just right to return what I need, any help is greatly appreciated =)

Here is what I have so far

```js
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { $match: {
            _id: { $in: [ObjectId("55158b0bd6076278295cf022"), ObjectId("55158b0bd6076278295cf021"), ObjectId("55158b0bd6076278295cf01f")   ] }
        }
    },
    { $project: { attributes: 1 }},
    { $group: { _id: '$attributes' } }

])
```

Which products this output:

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "shirt_size" : "S",
                "shirt_color" : "Blue",
                "custom_attr" : "adsfasdf"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "shirt_size" : "M",
                "shirt_color" : "Green"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "shirt_size" : "L",
                "shirt_color" : "Red"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000,
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(1427475045, 1),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("54f7c1edf8e5ff44cec194b6")
    }
}
```

I feel like it is close and I am just missing the last step :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `$unwind` the array, and then `$group` it and use `$sum` to count the appearance, then everything with `sum > 1` is a duplicate.

Links:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Comment: Can you give an example of grouping by keys...without knowing key names?  I think that seems to be my real stumbling block is that I do not know the attribute key names.  Perhaps the best way is just in code to obtain the values and iterate through

Comment: You can't do that. The only operation you can do with keys (no value involved) in MongoDB is `$exists`. `...` Your examples have `size` , `custom` and `material`. There must be some place in your application where those keys get set. `...` Another way would be to change the layout of the attributes, to something like `attributes: [ {k: "size", v: "L"}, {k:"custom", v: 7} ]`. It really depends on the querys you are executing which solution fits best. Sometimes the best solution might be so store the data twice with different arrangement of data.

Comment: I kind of had that feeling it wasnt possible.  For my particular use storing as keys makes the most sense....but it definitely seems to have its drawbacks.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

The `$addToSet(aggregation)` returns an array of unique values - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/

Using the following aggregation (get unique sizes per Doc):

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$testdoc"}, 
{$group : {_id: "$_id", size: {$addToSet: "$testdoc.attributes.size"}}}
])
```

Gives the following result:

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("551621fe6155a7741a0d328a"),
        "size" : [
            "M",
            "L"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("551621fe6155a7741a0d328b"),
        "size" : [
            "L"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("551621fe6155a7741a0d3289"),
        "size" : [
            "S",
            "M",
            "L"
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

The following aggregation returns unique sizes across all docs:

```
db.coll1.aggregate([ 
    {$unwind : "$testdoc"}, 
    {$group : 
         {_id: "AllSizes", size: {$addToSet: "$testdoc.attributes.size"}}} ])
```

Result:

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "AllSizes",
        "size" : [
            "S",
            "M",
            "L"
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Based on the following Docs:

```
> db.coll1.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("551621fe6155a7741a0d3289"),
"testdoc" : [
    {
        "sku" : "123",
        "attributes" : {
            "size" : "L",
            "custom" : 7
        }
    },
    {
        "sku" : "456",
        "attributes" : {
            "size" : "M"
        }
    },
    {
        "sku" : "abc",
        "attributes" : {
            "material" : "cotton",
            "size" : "S"
        }
    }
]
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("551621fe6155a7741a0d328a"),
"testdoc" : [
    {
        "sku" : "123",
        "attributes" : {
            "size" : "L",
            "custom" : 7
        }
    },
    {
        "sku" : "456",
        "attributes" : {
            "size" : "M"
        }
    },
    {
        "sku" : "abc",
        "attributes" : {
            "material" : "cotton",
            "size" : "M"
        }
    }
]
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("551621fe6155a7741a0d328b"),
"testdoc" : [
    {
        "sku" : "123",
        "attributes" : {
            "size" : "L",
            "custom" : 7
        }
    },
    {
        "sku" : "456",
        "attributes" : {
            "size" : "L"
        }
    },
    {
        "sku" : "abc",
        "attributes" : {
            "material" : "cotton",
            "size" : "L"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that I do not know that it is 'size'...it could be 'color' or anything...I need to be able to have it grab distinct values that they share. Sorry for not drawing more attention to it